# Smartface.io MQTT plugin

Tags: smartface.io

I need to use a mqtt client in smartface.io and was wondering if someone has developed a plugin or can advice how to do it. Actually the broker does not support websockets 
Thanks

Comment: Please read this page to learn how to make a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in SmartFace for MQTT so you need to implement this yourself.

A good option for beginners might be another product like: B4A https://www.b4x.com/b4a.html .. where the community have already created a lot of libraries/resources.

https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/jmqtt-official-android-mqtt-client.59497/